# How to get VSCode to "open as new file" from Go To File dialog

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have recently switched to VSCode, and am loving it, except for one specific thing that drives me nuts.

My "goto" command is {Command+P}, the easy search-and-open-file bar. If I type the name of a file into this bar and it does not exist, I want to be able to hit ENTER and have it open a tab editing that file as a new file. This is the behavior I would get in old-school Windows Notepad, or in mvim `:e <filename>`, but I can't figure out how to do it in VSCode.

Is there a toggle or a plugin I can use to get this behavior straight out of the Go To File dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

No, there's no way to do this using {Command+P}. This is strictly a file finder and I've yet to see any plugin that changes the behavior.

If you're using the VsCodeVim plugin, an almost-as-good approach is just `:e <file>` - immediately open a new buffer editing the given file. There's no tab autocomplete this way, but you just have to live with that.